# Update database via stored procedure from code-behind fails to update

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have worked on this, but unable to figure why my update fails. I'm not big on SQL. I wrote a simple stored procedure.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].sp_UpdateTeamMemberProfile
    @TeamMemberId int OUTPUT,
    @FirstName varchar(25),
    @LastName varchar(30),  
    @ContactNumber varchar (20),
    @ContactExt varchar (20) ,  
    @EmailAddress varchar(100),
    @Fax varchar (25),
    @LocationCity varchar (20),
    @LocationState varchar (20),
    @BeginWorkHrs int,
    @BeginWorkTime   varchar  (20) ,
    @EndWorkHrs  int ,
    @EndWorkTime varchar (20) ,
    @ZONE Varchar (20),
    @TeamMemberLanId varchar (20),
    @ManagerId varchar (20),
    @UpdateDate datetime
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN
       UPDATE dbo.LoanOwnerStamp
       SET FirstName = @FirstName,
           LastName = @LastName,
           ContactNumber = @ContactNumber,
           ContactExt = @ContactExt ,
           EmailAddress = @EmailAddress,
           Fax = @Fax, 
           LocationCity = @LocationCity, 
           LocationState = @LocationState,
           BeginWorkHrs = @BeginWorkHrs,
           BeginWorkTime = @BeginWorkTime,
           EndWorkHrs = @EndWorkHrs,
           EndWorkTime = @EndWorkTime, 
           Zone = @Zone,
           TeamMemberLanId = @TeamMemberLanId,
           ManagerId = @ManagerId ,
           UpdatedDate = @UpdateDate
       WHERE  
           TeamMemberLanId = @TeamMemberLanId 
           AND TeamMemberId = @TeamMemberId
     END 

     SET @TeamMemberId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

     RETURN @TeamMemberId
 END
```

Now the code behind follows...

```
using (SqlCommand updatetLSTeamMember = new SqlCommand("sp_UpdateTeamMemberProfile", myConnection))
{
    updatetLSTeamMember.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = txtFirstName.Text;
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = txtLastName.Text;
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@ContactNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = txtContactNumber.Text;
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@ContactExt", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = txtContactExt.Text;
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtEmailAddress.Text;
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@Fax", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = txtFax.Text;
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@LocationCity", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = txtLocationCity.Text;
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@LocationState", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = txtState.Text;
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@BeginWorkHrs", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlBeginHrs.SelectedValue.ToString();
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@BeginWorkTime", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = ddlBeginTime.SelectedValue.ToString();
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@EndWorkHrs", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlEndHrs.SelectedValue.ToString();
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@EndWorkTime", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = ddlEndTime.SelectedValue.ToString();
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@Zone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = ddlZone.SelectedItem.Text;
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@TeamMemberLanId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = txtTeamMemberLaniId.Text;
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@ManagerId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = gblUserId;
    updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@UpdateDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();

    pID = updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@TeamMemberId", SqlDbType.Int);  // I'm thinking this is a culprit
    pID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;  // are these assignment correct.

    try
    {
        if (updatetLSTeamMember.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            updatetLSTeamMember.Connection.Open();
        }

        updatetLSTeamMember.ExecuteNonQuery();  // code bombs out here 

        string idcat = updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters["@TeamMemberId"].Value.ToString();
```

Now my questions are in several places, is my `Parameter.Direction` output correct and is it correct from a stored procedure perspective?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Why do you use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` on UPDATE? It only makes sense on INSERT

Comment: `AND so the rest fo the cod follows ...` - this makes me nervous that the problem is in the part of the code not included. Please post all of your code.

Comment: so should i say return 0 for success and how to capture that in code behind is something i have not done. Thanks for letting me know about it.

Comment: sure let me add the code

Comment: @Guru - Have you run this stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio and watch it work with hard-coded values?

Comment: No i did not try that piece let me see if that works to begin with. Thanks

Comment: I hard coded values to the sp and ran it and db table was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a value I would suggest creating another variable in the stored procedure instead of using a value that you use for input.

This is what I would do:

```
@returnValue int OUTPUT
@TeamMemberId int,
@FirstName varchar(25),
@LastName varchar(30),  
@ContactNumber varchar (20),
@ContactExt varchar (20) ,  
@EmailAddress varchar(100),
@Fax varchar (25),
@LocationCity varchar (20),
@LocationState varchar (20),
@BeginWorkHrs int,
@BeginWorkTime   varchar  (20) ,
@EndWorkHrs  int ,
@EndWorkTime varchar (20) ,
@ZONE Varchar (20),
@TeamMemberLanId varchar (20),
@ManagerId varchar (20),
@UpdateDate datetime
```

AS

BEGIN

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

   UPDATE dbo.LoanOwnerStamp
   SET FirstName = @FirstName,
       LastName = @LastName,
       ContactNumber = @ContactNumber,
       ContactExt = @ContactExt ,
       EmailAddress = @EmailAddress,
       Fax = @Fax, 
       LocationCity = @LocationCity, 
       LocationState = @LocationState,
       BeginWorkHrs = @BeginWorkHrs,
       BeginWorkTime = @BeginWorkTime,
       EndWorkHrs = @EndWorkHrs,
       EndWorkTime = @EndWorkTime, 
       Zone = @Zone,
       TeamMemberLanId = @TeamMemberLanId,
       ManagerId = @ManagerId ,
       UpdatedDate = @UpdateDate
   WHERE  
       TeamMemberLanId = @TeamMemberLanId 
       AND TeamMemberId = @TeamMemberId 

 SET @returnValue= SCOPE_IDENTITY()

 RETURN @returnValue
```

END

And on your code behind:

EDIT:You also need to add this:

```
updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamMemberId",  int.Parse(txtTeamMemberId.Text)); // or wherever you are getting the team member id from.



pID = updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters.Add("@returnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
pID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

string idcat = updatetLSTeamMember.Parameters["@returnValue"].Value.ToString();
```

NOTE: I have never used SCOPE_IDENTITY() On an Update. You might want to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return something in case of success - u can use `@@ROWCOUNT` instead of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - it will return number of rows affected by the update.

So if 0 is returned - you will know that no records were updated.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but you're updating record based on where condition where you're using TeamMemberId (Output parameter), but not providing any value to it in c# side. The syntax si corect for output parameter but you're using it in where clause, what is the value,...
The Scope Identity part will be executed after executing the update command